# Pipelining get-content to own function

Tags: function, powershell, pipeline

I'm trying to write a powershell function that receives a list of files from the get-content commandlet by piplining and processes them.
The pipeline looks like this:

```
get-content D:\filelist.txt | test-pipeline
```

For simplicity sake the function below should just show each line of the textfile.

```
function test-pipeline
{
<#
.Synopsis
#>

  [CmdletBinding( SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]

  Param([Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
                   ValueFromPipeLine = $true)]
        [array]$filelist

       )



    foreach ($item in $filelist)
    {
        $item
    }


}
```

My  filelist is a normal .txt file and looks like this.

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

No matter what type of parameter I pipe to the function, it never works and shows only the last line of the text file in the $filelist variable. Can anybody help? Powershell Version is v2
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The reason you see only your last line requires digging a bit into the nature of pipeline-able PowerShell functions. In the absence of explicit begin/process/end blocks that Swonkie alluded to, all code in the function operates as if it is in the `end` block, i.e. it is as if you wrote:

```
function test-pipeline
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $true)][array]$filelist
  )
  END {
    $filelist
  }
}
```

But `$filelist`, being a pipeline variable, has only the *current* value in it when fed pipeline data; the `end` block runs when the pipeline input is exhausted, thus `$filelist` contains just the last value. Simply changing that `end` block to a `process` block--where it runs for each value in the pipeline, will give you the desired output:

```
function test-pipeline
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $true)][array]$filelist
  )
  PROCESS {
    $filelist
  }
}
```

And notice that you do not need any kind of loop there--the pipeline is already providing the "loop".

---

That is just one of several ways to process pipeline data. Here's a close variant, which is a bit shorter: use `filter` instead of `function`, because `filter` with no explicit blocks operates as if all code is in the `process` block.

```
filter test-pipeline
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $true)][array]$filelist
  )
  $filelist
}
```

To delve further into the fascinating and arcane world of writing functions for pipelining, take a look at the in-depth analysis I wrote, [Down the Rabbit Hole: A Study in PowerShell Pipelines, Functions, and Parameters](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/), published on Simple-Talk.com. Enjoy your PowerShell adventures!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of function try filter:

```
filter Test-Pipeline {
   ...
}
```

This is basically a function with a processing block (which you need to process pipeline objects). Alternatively you can write a function with this block and optional begin and end blocks:

```
function Test-Pipeline {
    begin {
    }
    process {
        ...
    }
    end {
    }
}
```

More info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh413265.aspx